# Show output in multiple div's using XSLT

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I am trying to print output like this this generated by just replacing

```
xsl:value-of select ="@new_bname"/> with A and other 

xsl:value-of select ="@new_bname"/> with B.
```

[image: Output i want]

but i am getting output like this

[image: Output i am getting which i don't want]

My html code including xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="//bankinfo/items">


                <div class="col-sm-12 pad0">
                  <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 != 0">
                <div class="col-sm-6 pad0l sm-pad0r">
                  <button class="btn-block border-grey text-c pad5 radius-20 bg-grey outline-none ">
                    <a href="/ifsc-code-v1.aspx?page_mode=2&amp;bank_url={@url_bank}" >
                      <xsl:value-of select ="@new_bname"/>

                    </a>
                  </button>
                </div>
                   </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
                <div class="col-sm-6 pad0r sm-pad0l sm-marg5t">
                  <button class="btn-block border-grey text-c pad5 radius-20 bg-grey outline-none ">
                    <a href="/ifsc-code-v1.aspx?page_mode=2&amp;bank_url={@url_bank}" >
                    <xsl:value-of select ="@new_bname"/> 
                    </a>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </xsl:if>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="pad5t"></div>

              </xsl:for-each>
```

I want bank name 1 at A and bank name 2 at B place.
Same continued till the last item in my `XML`.

**EDIT:**
`@new_bname` is coming from **DB** via the controller and then rendered via `XSLT` to `HTML`.
I am iterating with `<xsl:for-each>` for all the items in the `XML` and putting it on `HTML`.
But i want First and second bank name side by side like picture number 1.
I want the first `@new_bname` in the first div and next `@new_bname` in next div. but like this, i am generating same bankNames in 2 different columns

**Edit 2**
Expected output 1 by hardcoding the bankname values

**[image: expected out put]**

XML structure

```
<items url_bank="a-c-b-ld" new_bname="ICICI"/>

<items url_bank="a-d-c-bank" new_bname="HDFC"/>

<items url_bank="a-m-c-b" new_bname="Bank OF AMERICA"/>
```

Comment: This not an XSLT problem, but an HTML/CSS problem. Are you able to create your desired layout without XSLT?

Comment: @wasmachien first output that I showed you is generated by bootstrap and css only. The data i am getting is raw XML from backend with multiple bank names. I want to show that like the picture number 1.

Comment: In that case you should look at the source of the bootstrap page and try to recreate it with XSLT. Or post the bootstrap code here so people can help.

Comment: @wasmachien bootstrap and all code is fine, all i want is getting first item in  first div and next item in other div. Just like a TR with TWO TD or more and different data in all TD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<b><xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::items[1]/@url_bank"/></b>
<b><xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::items[2]/@url_bank"/></b>
```

Using the above code i am getting the desired attributes

Using this i am getting the desired output in 3 div's.
Change '`position() mod`' according to your need and increase the number `<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::items[<!--1,2,3,4(any number)-->]" />`

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what your expected output should be, but this simplified XSLT may give you at a starting point to get your required structure...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//bankinfo/items[position() mod 2 != 0]">
    <div class="col-sm-12 pad0">
      <div class="col-sm-6 pad0l sm-pad0r">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 pad0r sm-pad0l sm-marg5t">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::items[1]" />
      </div>
    </div> 
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:value-of select ="@new_bname"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I've used a template here to avoid any repeated code.

Comment: I added the expected output picture. Just take a look. Thanks @tim-c

Comment: I tried your method and it is giving me output like i wanted in two columns but what if i want output in 3 columns like above what changes should i make and HOW to take their corresponding @url in this <a href="/ic-v1.aspx?page_mode=2&amp;bank_url={@url_bank}" >

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me. Beer on me